# How can I draw Voronoi regions in curved surfaces in AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad, geometry

**How can I automatically compute and draw/display the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of a given set of vertices on a surface in AutoCAD?**

A "[Voronoi Sketch Generator](https://apps.autodesk.com/ACD/en/Detail/HelpDoc?appId=1006119760063675415&appLang=en&os=Mac#inunininfo)" is the best I could come up with on a google search.

Quite close, but:

- It doesn't seem to work for curved surfaces, only flat 2d planes
- It is a plugin for Fusion360, not AutoCAD
- It doesn't let me define the set of vertices of the diagram (it generates them randomly)

It is my understanding that I can import an AutoCAD drawing to Fusion360 and then export it back to AutoCAD. Maybe tuning up this plugin for this task would be my best choice?

Being a telecommunications software engineer I have near zero experience with AutoCAD, so I apologize for my absolute ignorance on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Computing a Voronoi diagram on a surface is not an easy problem, and there is unlikely to be a solution within AutoCAD.
You might start with this paper, and work backward & forward through its references using Google Scholar:

---

[image: CatVD]

---

> Yan, Dong‐Ming, Bruno Lévy, Yang Liu, Feng Sun, and Wenping Wang. "Isotropic remeshing with fast and exact computation of restricted Voronoi diagram." In *Computer Graphics Forum*, vol. 28, no. 5, pp. 1445-1454. Blackwell Publishing Ltd, 2009. ([Authors' link](http://i.cs.hku.hk/~gfxgroup/projects/remesh/index.html).)

Answer (score 1):

1) I usually use online voronoizing tool (**https://www.voronator.com/**) for generating voronoization in 3D file.

- The website asks you to upload your 3D file for generating the
  voronoi.
- It supports formats like **stl, stla, stlb, ply, off, obj, dae, 3ds**
- but the file has to be less than **20mb**.
- You can even import a file which is already meshed.
- There is also an advance settings option, where you can select the
  output format, number of holes and thickness of the layer.
- You can get output in two formats, either an **STL** or **PLY** file.

2) The second solution would be **"Voronoi Sketch Generator"** add-in for fusion 360. The add-in asks you for some reference values to generate a sketch. You have options to select the number holes and also you can choose whether the holes have to be straight or curved. 
There are also plenty of youtube tutorial videos on how to use this tool which can come in handy for you. I'll post the links of videos which I found useful for me.

- https://youtu.be/9YEEd81MeCU
- https://youtu.be/6q51guUtB4I

What ever may be the option, but you still have to export and import across the softwares to have job done.